# How to interact with DB from a button on Django when your 'item' change every refresh (Python)

Tags: python, django, database, button, random

I'm looking for a way to change an 'item' (the one displayed on the page) in the DB.
But first, I should have 2 buttons on the page. And secondly, The 'item' shown is random from the DB.
So the problem is : How can I change the item info in the DB knowing that the button will refresh the page to send it in the request. (I remind you that my item is random and so, change every refresh)

So, I need a way to change it or a way to randomize the page but not when I send a POST request

My views.py : (Messy but it's ok xD)

```py
def review(request):
    loop = True
    i = 0
    while loop and i < len(Cartes.objects.filter(user_id_shared_id__exact=request.user.id).values_list('pk', flat=True))*4:
        i = i + 1
        pks = Cartes.objects.filter(user_id_shared_id__exact=request.user.id).values_list('pk', flat=True)
        if len(pks) == 0:
            loop = False
            return redirect('/create/')
        random_pk = choice(pks)
        card = Cartes.objects.get(pk=random_pk)
        obj, created = Review.objects.get_or_create(
            card_id_id=card.id,
            user_id_id=request.user.id,
        )
        print(card.id, "///", obj.id)
        date_3_days = obj.review_date + datetime.timedelta(days=3)
        date_7_days = obj.review_date + datetime.timedelta(days=7)
        date_21_days = obj.review_date + datetime.timedelta(days=21)
        date_42_days = obj.review_date + datetime.timedelta(days=42)
        if obj.review_level == 1:
            loop = False
        elif obj.review_level == 2 and datetime.date.today() >= date_3_days:
            loop = False
        elif obj.review_level == 3 and datetime.date.today() >= date_7_days:
            loop = False
        elif obj.review_level == 4 and datetime.date.today() >= date_21_days:
            loop = False
        elif obj.review_level == 5 and datetime.date.today() >= date_42_days:
            loop = False
        else:
            loop = True

    if request.method=='POST' and 'btnform1' in request.POST:
        print(card.id)
        obj.review_level = 1
        obj.review_date = datetime.date.today()
        obj.save()
        return redirect('review')
    else:
        pass

    if request.method=='POST' and 'btnform2' in request.POST:
        print(card.id)
        obj.review_date = datetime.date.today()
        if obj.review_level != 5:
            obj.review_level = obj.review_level + 1
        obj.save()
        return redirect('review')
    else:
        pass

    context = {'card':card}
    return render(request, 'card/review.html', context)
```

My template:

```html
<body>
    <div class="page">
        <h1>{{ card.title }}</h1>
        <div class="carte">
            <p> {{ card.content }} </p>
            <form method='POST'>
                {% csrf_token %}
                {{form1.as_p}}
                <button type="submit" name="btnform1" value={{obj}}>Je n'ai pas trouvé :'c</button>
            </form>
                <form method='POST'>
                {% csrf_token %}
                {{form2.as_p}}
            <button type="submit" name="btnform2">J'ai trouvé !</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way :
Create a buffer page where it randomize. Then redirect to the page where you want to display the thing you randomize. You can do it with a dynamic url.

to redirect use it like that

return redirect('review', myUrlArg=viewArg)

Hope it can help someone